# Propagating updates (and isolating nodes) practices

Tags: neo4j

I'm thinking on implementing an on-line pseudo-schema update mechanism for my application. I'm using an embedded HA-version of neo4j (2.1/2.2-milestones).

What I mean by the *pseudo-schema update* is a set of new properties (and possibly relationships (possibly even to the new nodes)) being added to the already existing ones. Say, I have

```
(h :Word {title : "node"})-[s :Synonym]->(v :Word {title : "vertex"})
```

And I'd like the next version of my super-awesome app to have this structure:

```
(h :Word :Adjective {title : "hot"})-[s :Synonym]->(b :Word :Adjective {title : "balmy"})
(h)-[a :Antonym]->(c: Word {title : "cold"})
// I'd like to have index on `titles` of all `Adjective`s as well!
```

And since my app is that awesome, I'd like it to be available for as much time as possible so I have a 3 (5, 7 etc.) node cluster with some redundancy.

Now, the perfect scenario for me would be to somehow 'pull' a node from the cluster (while the rest of them is serving that delicious content) and make changes in offline mode: create indices and relationships, add labels and indices and so on. After that, the node is plugged back into the cluster and changes slowly propagate.

This situation is in some way related to the limitations of the CAP theorem, since I can't see the way to make the 'schema' upgrade atomic while staying consistent with all the data updates which can happen during the upgrade. That is, I can't provide update atomicity while retaining consistency. I would like for the outer world to see the update as seamless as possible, but it looks like I can't achieve it in a single step.

The problems are:

1. (As usually) there might be some new data that was created on the outdated nodes during the update process.
2. I don't know if it's possible to propagate the changes from the node that's been outdated if it's not a master (hence the question - can I force-assign the cluster's master?)

The question is whether I'm on the right track here and what procedures do  you employ if you face scenarios like this? Is there any migration tool that addresses my issues? Or maybe there is some community effort I can participate in to create something like this if it's possible?

In general, what I need is a design advice rather than final technical solution.

Comment: In that case programmers.se might be a better place, but check their help center first....

Comment: @rene, I'd be glad to see a solution as well. Also, neo4j community, not that vast as it were, is largely centered here on SO, so the chances of me getting my answer here are much higher than anywhere else.

Comment: Hmm, OK, you run the risk though of being off-topic on SO ... but we will see what happens...

Comment: "Pseudo-schema update" I think requires more elaboration.  Why wouldn't the solution simply be to write some cypher which updates a batch of nodes at a time, dividing this whole transform process into reasonable sized/spaced batches?  I think the way you're describing your perfect scenario already presumes a particular implementation approach; take a step back and provide some more info/background on how the rest of the world should see the DB as it's updating.

Comment: If you should fail to get good feedback here (which is very possible as the way you've posed the question isn't likely to have a single correct answer) you might also consider here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, I've updated the question, but I really don't think that it's much of a clarification. Maybe I should just deal with the fact that all the major updates require some downtime, e.g. like it happens here on SO sometimes.

Comment: You say that the outside world should see this as seamlessly as possible, but if you're upgrading the basic schema, won't you inevitably be breaking some of the data consumers (who expect the old schema)?  Even if you could do what you wanted technically, I'm not sure how a change like this could be seamless, unless the data consumers are somehow schema-agnostic. Is that the case?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, that's a really good question. I believe there are 2 major cases: append-like updates, which aren't breaking compatibility (i.e. an update results in new 'schema' being a super-set of previous one), and the case which breaks compatibility, like 'splitting' a label into 2+ (e.g. `:Media` -> `:Movie` and `:Song`) etc. Even if we consider the first case, it's not clear how to execute the update in a way that won't result in users seeing different chunks of data in a different state - although it won't break compatibility or something, it still looks pretty shabby.

Comment: I'm not sure. My intuition is that you have multiple points where this *must* break; your design can choose where it *will/should* break, but your design can't choose *whether* it breaks.  Schema (to me) usually implies data needs to be structured that way, so if you had a new one, you'd probably eventually want a mechanism to prevent logging new data in the old schema, even if new is a superset of old. Otherwise "new consumers" get partial results, and think they're complete.

Comment: I think more design is warranted before requesting a solution. E.g. split out new vs. old data consumers vs. producers.  Under new regime, who will display which behaviors? What is the desired system response? What negative happens from downtime? What are the tradeoffs (e.g. might more consistent data overall and less "propagation time" be worth the negatives of downtime) - etc.

Comment: Yes, those are valid points. That's why my question seems so broad and unsure - I'm just standing in the darkness poking everything with a stick. When I said I'd like to know more about best practices I meant exactly this - not just an advice on how to get a compromise between everything I mentioned, but rather an advice on what is a usual practice with this kind of things.

Comment: by far not an answer, but http://www.liquigraph.org is an effort to handle structural db changes as part of your code.

Comment: In Neo4j HA when you bring a node back into the cluster whose data has changed, it is considered branched data, parked on the side and that node pulls new updates from the current master.

Comment: Perhaps what you can do is to put a proxy in front of your cluster, which can hold of client requests for a while and do the schema updates while the requests are waiting and allow them again when the schema updates are through?

Comment: Or you could run two concurrent clusters and switch them into one hot and one spare and run the schema updates on the spare cluster which after they are done becomes the hot one?

Comment: @MichaelHunger, I did consider the on-the-fly swapping solution, but there still is a problem of the data which is being modified on the hot cluster during the process of schema updates on the spare one. Out final decision was to make our peace with the fact that critical structural updates are practically impossible to resolve without going to at least read-only mode (and having as small a downtime as possible in case that's inevitable).